# Want to know to how to render particular data from the chunk of data which is stored in an array

Tags: reactjs, api, bar-chart

I want to know how to render a particular chunk of data from an array of large data.

I am storing the data in an array from API call, but I want the particular data from that array not all of it, and render it to the bar chart and the most important part is it needs to be take from the user Interface to sort the data.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
          displayMenu: false,
          country_Claim_Type : []  // storing the data in this array
        };

     this.OnClick = this.OnClick.bind(this);
   };
```

This is the API call code which will get invoke when a user click the country from the drop-down menu.

```
OnClick (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/AMS/country`)
    .then(res => {
      const countries = res.data;
      const claimcount = [];
      const claimtype = [];
      countries.forEach(element => {
        claimcount.push(element.COUNT);
        claimtype.push(element.CLT_NAME);
      });
      this.setState({ 
        country_Claim_Type: {
           labels: claimtype,
          datasets:[
             {
                label:'',
                data: claimcount ,
                backgroundColor:[

                 'rgba(255,105,145,0.6)',
                 'rgba(155,100,210,0.6)',
                 'rgb(255, 0, 64)',
                 'rgb(191, 255, 0)',
                 'rgb(0, 255, 255)',
                 'rgb(128, 0, 255)'
              ]
             }
          ]
       }
       });
    });
  }
```

Here it is rendering all the data that is stored in the array but I want to show the data of a particular country on clicking in the drop-down by the user.

```
<Col style={{marginTop:30+"px", left:370+"px"}}>
                    <Card>
                    <CardHeader>Claim Types</CardHeader>
                      <CardBody>
                      <Bar  data={this.state.country_Claim_Type}
                  options={{
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    }} />
                  </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                </Col>
```

This is the code for drop-down so when the user click any country from the drop-down it should render that country's data that is stored in the array, not all the data of the array.

```
<div  style={textStyle} className="dropdown" style = {{background:"white",width:"200px"}} >
          <div className="button" onClick={this.DropdownMenu} style={{ right:100+"px"}}> Country </div>
          { this.state.displayMenu ? (
                     <ul>
<li><a className="active" href="/Main" onClick={this.OnClick}>Argentina</a></li>
              <li><a className="active_1" href="/Main" >Belize</a></li>
              <li><a className="active_2" href="/Main" >Bermuda</a></li>
              <li><a className="active" href="/Main" >Bolivia</a></li>
              <li><a className="active_1" href="/Main" >Bonaire</a></li>
              <li><a className="active_2" href="/Main" >Brazil</a></li>
              <li><a className="active" href="/Main" >Canada</a></li>
              <li><a className="active" href="/Main" >Ecuador</a></li>

              </ul>

             ):(null)  }
          </div>
```

Comment: And the problem is? Do you get an error? If yes what is the error? From where does the error come? Or render isn't evoked on click?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a `state` variable to store the country that is selected using the dropdown.

And before passing data to the `Bar` component, you can filter this data using the `filter` method of Arrays.

Hope this Helps!